# Flex - Superscript of an icon/image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, itemrenderer

I am working on ActionScript 3.0 and came across a doubt. We can have 2 images in a single cell of datagrid via itemRenderer property.

I want to show an icon as a superscript to some text present in the cell itself.

How can this be written ? Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Flex 3 based on the question's tag.  Within your custom item renderer, you'll need to use an `HBox` with `verticalAlign="top"`:

```
<mx:HBox verticalAlign="top">
    <mx:Label text="My label" />
    <mx:Image source="superscript_icon.jpg" width="6" height="6" />
</mx:HBox>
```

If I've misunderstood anything, please include a code sample for what you currently have and details on where you want the icon added.